# two sentences, which is better?

Tags: grammar

There are two sentences. I do not know which is better in grammar. Is there any difference?

1. Vegetables are good for health, which can be found in many areas in this country.
2. Vegetables are good for health and can be found in many areas in this country.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Both sentences are entirely grammatical, but I suspect that you want to express a particular idea. Please edit this question to say what it is that you want your chosen sentence to mean. Asking "Which is grammatical" is proof-reading and unhelpful.

Comment: @Andrew I’d say both sentences are **ungrammatical**: _health_ requires some kind of determiner to work here.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence means that *the fact that vegetables are good for health can be found in many areas of the country*. It is confusing.

If you have two ideas in the sentence and you join them with *which* and you put a comma before it, then the second part of the sentence refers to the meaning of the whole first part of the sentence. For example:

> Me and my friends always eat lots of vegetables, which is good for our health.

The sentence number two is fine and clear.

Comment: Actually, I want to use "which" to indicate "vegetables" in the first sentence.

Comment: @ZhiwuLi You can’t. Not the way the sentence is currently phrased, at least. Relative markers like _that_ and _which_ always refer back to the **last** possible element before them. _Which_ can refer back to either a noun phrase or an entire clause. That means that it can refer to two possible things in your example: “Vegetables are good for your health” (clause) or “health” (noun phrase). In other words, you’re either saying that you can find your health in many areas in the country or that you can find that vegetables are good for your health in many areas in the country. Neither works.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Second sentence is much better.

1 Vegetables are good for health, which *[health??]* can be found in many areas in this country.
2 Vegetables are good for health and *[vegetables]* can be found in many areas in this country.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing it, why not:

Vegetables, which/that are good for health ,can be found in many areas in this country.

Comment: That changes the meaning to 'Those vegetables which are good for health can be found in many ...'. You need commas round _which are good for health_.